# addeventlistener within a function

Tags: javascript, html

hey guys i am trying to use addeventlistener in a function, this code has to change the style and of the given element in the parameter. the code is as follows

```
function change(elem, prop, value){
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
        elem.style.prop = value
  }, false);
}
change(document.getElementById('demo'), 'backgroundColor', 'red');
```

Comment: `prop` doesn't exist in `elem.style`.

Comment: Do you have a question? Or are you hoping someone will notice that your `prop` property name is the same as the parameter, and will infer from that that you want to use the parameter as the property?

Comment: See if this helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators. Look for "bracket notation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use bracket notation instead of dot notation:

```
elem.style[prop] = value
```

because `prop` is not the name of the property. Instead, you want the string contained in `prop`.